# How can I check next iteration in for loop?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a JS website. I used Selenium and everything works well until I got this error. The website has a table and I am working on it.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[26]/td[4]"}
  (Session info: chrome=84.0.4147.125)
```

In the XPath
25th and 27th iterations have 4. td

```
/html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[26]/td[4]
```

but 26th doesn't have a 4th td.

I try to solve the problem with using "pass in loop" like this:

```
if(bool(driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[26]/td[***+str(j)+***] ").is_enabled)):pass
```

But as soon as selenium sees the path it is giving an error without checking. I understand that **"is_enable"** method works for nothing.

The question is: how can I pass the iteration without Selenium interrupt?

Comment: `try`/`except NoSuchElementException` should solve your problem

Comment: I didn’t try it yet I will let you know on sunday. Thanks alot.

Comment: it works!!! Thank you so much it passed without any error with the following code.

try:
```            driver.find_element_by_xpath("./html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td["+str(j)+"]/table/tbody/tr["+str(i)+"]/td[4]")
        except NoSuchElementException:
            continue
` @JaSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("./html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td["+str(j)+"]/table/tbody/tr["+str(i)+"]/td[4]")
except NoSuchElementException:
            
continue
```

If there is no element in the XPath, It returns null. It works. Thank you @JaSon

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried something like this? (You can easily boot it up with `for` loop)

```
if driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[26]/td[1(Can't boosted with for loop):
    print("Found object")
else:
    print("Can't find object")
```

Comment: What does `td[XYZ]` mean?

Comment: @JaSON You can easily iterate through the objects and check if it's enabled/visible and if yes, do something. I do not think that `Try/Except` option that you have suggested if good enough

Comment: `NoSuchElementException` is not about visibility. OP is trying to handle node that is absent in HTML-tree. How your solution can be useful in this case?

Comment: If you will iterate through and check if the element does exist, you will not have this type of errors `NoSuchElementException ` = you do not need to `try/except` them

Comment: Where is the code for *"...check if the element does exist"*? I don't see it in your answer

Comment: In case `find_element_by_xpath(XPATH)` found nothing `NoSuchElementException` should be raised. `if`/`else` wouldn't work here

Comment: The problem here selenium. If there is no element in the path, selenium shut down the code. [link text] (https://www.konya.bel.tr/halfiyatlari.php). As you can see there are orange rows and I have to pass these rows. I hope the link helps.